# What is the reason for appearance of "misaligned reference"?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, error

I have written a big contract with a lot of template functions and can find a place, which causes

```
2018-11-19T08:14:11.454 thread-0   binaryen.hpp:608              translate_one        ] misaligned reference
```

appearance. What are the reasons of that message appearing? Is it okay to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/6191), it is OK to ignore this warning. However I have no idea what it actually means and I am curious to find out.